incorrectly applied syntax highlighting
Recently someone has been editing questions to mark every single <pre> block for YAML syntax-highlighting, even though the contents are not YAML – sometimes resulting in the post being a mess of colors when the YAML rules are applied to unrelated text.
examples:

https://superuser.com/revisions/1866952/2
https://superuser.com/revisions/1863901/2
https://superuser.com/revisions/1866692/4
https://superuser.com/revisions/1866524/5

Why is this being done? Is it automated? Is there a regex that decides "it has : so it must be YAML"?



Update: Given the downvotes as well as the lack of any response from grawity who tagged this question as “discussion” but has utterly not participated in any actual discussion, I can assume this post was mainly a complaint about the use of the yaml syntax highlighting and not a call for discussion.
There are all kinds of “hills to die on” in life (and Stack Exchange) so I will gladly discontinue using yaml for syntax highlighting of non-YAML items. In fact, after I posted my answer grawity went ahead and undid yaml syntax highlighting for three of the four posts he’s high-lighted; this one, this one and this one. So hey! I will not oppose these changes.
As for suggestions about improving the overall syntax highlighting stuff? I will consider it at a later point.
Original answer below…


“Recently someone…”

I am that “someone!” That “someone” is me!
You say this:

“incorrectly applied syntax highlighting”

And this:

“Why is this being done? Is it automated?”

It is not automated. It is all manually done by me.
And I say for many of the items I have edited while they are technically not yaml, they do benefit from the color coding that yaml highlighting provides.
In many of the cases, the items should technically be bash, sh or text but those options don’t color code the code fenced items at all. But choosing yaml nicely color codes items for easier reading/parsing.
I don’t believe there are any hard/fast rules for code fence highlighting; my goal is to just set code fenced items to be as readable and human parsable as possible.
PS: If the community is against syntax highlighting for readability and is strictly focused on the content that is fine. But let’s have some consensus.

The syntax highlighting for language is automated. The edits are manual. I'd say to an extent I'd expect syntax highlighting to be a lot less expected here than SO. (Not a downvote explaination. I'm still processing what I think about it)

"In many of the cases, the items should technically be bash, sh or text[, but] those options don’t color code the code fenced items at all." - sounds like a good feature request to turn on more options for highlighting. I'm also in the "don't misappropriate the highlighter" camp.

@Robotnik As for syntax highlighting feature requests, what has caught me out in the past is Syntax highlighting works in the preview only, not in the rendered post, whereby syntax highlighting works when you are previewing your post, but doesn't work in the rendered post. While not directly related to this question, thought it worth mentioning if anyone was going to raise a feature request.

@ChesterGillon an unfortunate difference between the client-side (preview) renderer and the server side (post) renderer. I'm fairly certain that bug has been raised on MSO or MSE before. I'll see if I can find it

@JourneymanGeek I have updated my answer with a preface that further explains my point of view. Grawity doesn’t want a discussion despite tagging this question as “discussion?” Whatever. I will stop the practice and maybe discuss improved syntax highlighting at a later date. I have no energy for this anymore.

@ChesterGillon See above.

@Robotnik Ditto. See above.
